# Eliminate null results from case query - no null values in source

Tags: sql-server, pivot, case, aggregate-functions, string-agg

I am trying to pull off a complicated aggregation and concatenation query to prep data for import to a website, aggregating multiple results rows and columns into one row per ID.

I'm almost there, except that I am getting a lot of NULL results despite there being no NULL values in the source data.

Source data:

| id | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | sometext | othertext | moretext | A2 |
| x1 | sometext | othertext | moretext | B1 |
| x1 | sometext | othertext | moretext | B2 |
| x2 | sometext | othertext | moretext | B1 |
| x2 | sometext | othertext | moretext | A2 |
| x2 | sometext | othertext | moretext | B1 |

The following:

```
select distinct id, 
case when type='A2' then string_agg (concat(cast (value_1 as nvarchar (max)),value_1,value_2,value_3)) end as type_A2, 
case when type='B1' then string_agg (concat(cast (value_1 as nvarchar (max)),value_1,value_2,value_3)) end as type_B1
from source
group by id, type
```

Produces:

| id | type_a2 | type_B1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | sometextothertextmoretext | NULL |
| x1 | NULL | sometextothertextmoretext |
| x2 | sometextothertextmoretext | NULL |
| x2 | NULL | sometextothertextmoretext |

When I try only running one column at a time, I still get some NULL results.

How do I get these results into one row per unique ID?

ie...

| id | type_a2 | type_B1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | sometextothertextmoretext | sometextothertextmoretext |
| x2 | sometextothertextmoretext | sometextothertextmoretext |
| x3 | etc | etc |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want one row per `id` - so, I would start by removing `type` from the `select` and `group by` clauses. Next, the `case` expression would go *inside* the aggregate functions. So:

```
select id,
    string_agg(case when type = 'A2' then concat(cast(value_1 as nvarchar(max)), value_1, value_2, value_3) end, ',') as type_a2,
    string_agg(case when type = 'B1' then concat(cast(value_1 as nvarchar(max)), value_1, value_2, value_3) end, ',') as type_b1
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: This is right, with one minor tweak: a separator clause is needed with string_agg. ie string_agg(case when type = 'A2' then concat(cast(value_1 as nvarchar(max)), value_1, value_2, value_3) end,**[SEPARATOR]**) as type_a2      Thanks very much - this had been driving me mental.

Comment: @smallnorthumbrianvillage: welcome. I added the missing separator to my answer.